# How to use @Body with @Field and @FormUrlEncoded?

Tags: android, http-post, retrofit2, android-json, square

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/post")
Call<Response> createPost(
        @Header("auth") String auth,
        @Field("id") String id,
        @Field("title") String title,
        @Body ContentData content);
```

By using this code am getting error saying "@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.". What should i do now ? I tried to send Object as String that also failed.

Comment: Use TypedInput..

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending form-data use Field for your parameters:

```
@Header("auth: YOUR_AUTH")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/post")
Call<Response> createPost(
    @Field("id") String id,
    @Field("title") String title
);
```

else if you are using other than form-data like application/json Send your body by @Body:

```
@Header("auth: YOUR_AUTH")
@POST("/api/post")
Call<Response> createPost(@Body ContentData content);
```

This all depends upon your requirements.